# Capitalize first letter of string on keydown input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the first letter to Uppercase when I write on the textbox.

I wrote the below code but it changes the letter in style of css and when I send it with form it send it with small word at first.
how can i transform to capitalize  in jquery?

here is my code :

```js
$('.capital').css('textTransform', 'capitalize');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="capital"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toUpperCase` and `substr` to get 1st letter and make it upper case.

```js
   
$(".capital").focusout(function() {
    var yourtext = $(this).val();
    alert(yourtext.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + yourtext.substr(1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="capital"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code always changes the first letter to uppercase. I think it's bad design to do so.

```js
var firstCapitalAlways= function (event) {
    var val = $(event.target).val();
    var firstLetterUpper = val[0] ? val[0].toUpperCase() : "";
    $(event.target).val(firstLetterUpper + val.substr(1, val.length));
}
 
var firstCapitalOnBlur = function(event) {
    var val = $(event.target).val();
    if(val){
        $(event.target).val(val[0].toUpperCase() + val.substr(0, val.length))
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Always</label>
<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="firstCapitalAlways(event);" class="capital"/>
<label>Onblur</label>
<input type="text" value="" onblur="firstCapitalOnBlur(event);" class="capital"/>
```